# Taylorseries , changing parameter to get another result

Tags: taylor-expansion

I know Taylorseries of  $ ln(1+x)= x -\frac{x}{2}+ \frac{x}{3}.... $, If i chnge $ln(1+x)$ to $ln(1+x^{2})$ , is it right to replace all X,s with $x^{2}$ ? I see people change sometime only one parameter to get result but i don't know exactly how they do it.

Comment: You can do that.  If $f(x) = \sum a_n x^n \implies f(x^2) = \sum a_n x^{2n}$  Assuming, of course, you stay inside the radius of convergence.

Comment: @Doug: Given the radius of convergence, it shouldn't be too hard to check…